# Swift help, please explain how this code works

Tags: swift, ios8

I came across this code and not sure how it can perform the operation such as (*, +, -, %). Can someone please explain how it knows that for example has to add the two number?

```
var operandStack = Array<Double>()

switch operation {
       case "×": performOperation { $0 * $1 }
       case "+": performOperation { $0 + $1 }


func performOperation(operation: (Double, Double)->Double)
{
    displayValue=operation(operandStack.removeLast(),
    operandStack.removeLast())
}

var displayValue: Double
{
    set {
        display.text = "\(newValue)"   
    }
    get {
        return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString
                                      (display.text!)!.doubleValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, the expression

```
{ $0 * $1 }
```

is a function (technically a [*closure expression*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID95)) that multiplies its first argument by its second. Parameters are numbered starting at zero.

The function is compatible with the type `(Double, Double)->Double` (note the power of type inference) and can thus be passed to `performOperation`.

Here is some more information from the Swift Developer Guide:

> Shorthand Argument Names
>
> Swift automatically provides shorthand argument names to inline closures, which can be used to refer to the values of the closure’s arguments by the names $0, $1, $2, and so on.
>
> If you use these shorthand argument names within your closure expression, you can omit the closure’s argument list from its definition, and the number and type of the shorthand argument names will be inferred from the expected function type. The in keyword can also be omitted, because the closure expression is made up entirely of its body:
>
> reversed = sorted(names, { $0 > $1 } )
>
> Here, $0 and $1 refer to the closure’s first and second String arguments.